# Query based on ManytoMany Field Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models on which I want to query based on ManytoMany Field:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    topping_name=models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Cart_Item(models.Model):
    pizza=models.ForeignKey(Pizza, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    toppings=models.ManyToManyField(Topping, blank=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField()
```

I have a list of toppings available with me. I want to query a `Cart_Item` where `toppings` field contains all the values in the list. For example if my list is `toppings_list=["Pepperoni","Mushroom"]`, then I want the `Cart_Item` where `toppings` contains only these 2 toppings. How can I query like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an option.

```py
cart_items = (Cart_Item.objects.annotate(num_toppings=Count('toppings'))\
.filter(num_toppings__exact=2))\
.filter(toppings__topping_name=toppings_list[0])\
.filter(toppings__topping_name=toppings_list[1])
```

If list includes many data, then you can chain querysets in a loop.

```
for topping in toppings_list:
    cart_items = cart_items.filter(toppings__topping_name=topping)
```

Comment: I don't get the sense why you have given an index of 0 for `toppings_list`. Anyway, it is missing something because even when it has one topping in common it gets that object. what i want is the object that that contains exactly the toppings that are mentioned, not less nor more.

Comment: I thought this would first filter by count of toppings and first value 'Pepperoni'. Then filter this queryset with second value  afterwards.

Comment: Do you have idea on how to exactly get it, even in the case when I will have 3 items in `toppings_list`. I think you are quite close, maybe any idea to how to achieve

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: I have edited. Can you check? Something like this would definitely work but I don't remember exact code.

Comment: Wait, we were doing wrong. We need to get the queryset for topping. Instead, we were doing string.

Comment: Didn't you say you needed exactly two?

Comment: If I understand your question, You mean get all the Cart Items which  have exactly these 2 toppings.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wanted that only. Anyway I extended on your way and figured out a way to achieve it. Although it is a little tedious but works and gives desired result.

Comment: Is that something like what now I've edited? I don't think solution would be too tedious but something like this,

Comment: Yeah, it is like this. I think it is tedious because I think there might even be a better way which we might not know.

Comment: As far as I know, only better way is raw query.